# Access database on Sharepoint 2010

Tags: 2010, web, microsoft-access

In our company, we have an Access database which is stored in a network shared folder and it is used as a back-end database. And every employee has a front-end version in their own computers. Now we are planning to move this access database to Sharepoint 2010 and we would like to access it from mobile devices. In this case, do you think Access Services on Sharepoint 2010 is the best solution for us? I googled about it and found that mobile view is not good at Access services.

What are your recommendations for moving our Access database to Sharepoint 2010? What would be the best practice for that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think yout best bet is use the Office 365(SharePoint Online) as access services available online.

I am sure you will get better experience over their, try a trial version.
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Build-and-publish-an-Access-database-to-SharePoint-e68bf007-410c-43b2-bf21-322ddbcf5411?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US

Comment: Thanks Wagas. Do you think I can publish my SPLIT database to SHarepoint 2010? On internet, I found some thoughts in forums saying that publishing an splitted access database to Sharepoint 2010 is not possible. Do you have any knowledge about that? http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-access/publish-a-split-database-to-sharepoint-using/1dc06e02-96eb-4389-9b04-4c80409b5616

Answer (score 0):

Access Services in SP2010 is for Access applications to manage SP list data. Unless you want to move the data to SP lists, that plan does not make sense. Access services in SP2013 and O365 is for applications that will store their data in SQL.

Of course, you can just store the front-end Access app out in a doclib (not the data, the app itself) and let people access the app. It will be downloaded to their desktop and it will run and access the back-end DB just like it works now.

This approach does not use SP for anything but as a delivery mechanism for the app.

Regards..Antelope